# python selenium loop through text box

Tags: python, selenium, loops, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking to loop through these integers, inputting each into a web browsers textbox. I've already set up the python code to open chrome, navigate to the site, login, and navigate to the text box (unfortunately it's at work - I can reattach it here tomorrow morning), but how do I get it to take the first user input from below, type it into the textbox - let's pretend its  `find_element_by_id('thetextbox')` - I'll get it to press the enter button at the bottom of the page here, but then navigate back to the same textbox as before and enter the second user input? And then how would it know to stop at however many integers were inputted?

Sorry if it's a bit confusing, I really should have sent the code to myself :(

```
x = raw_input("Enter list of integers separated by a space:")
integers = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
```

Comment: you can also use class name, if its unique or if you can input any static class to it and then try to access that with
selenium.getAttribute(//xpath@class); might help

Comment: As you say you need a loop. Using a `for` loop over your `integers` array is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Given the info above you can do:

```
x = raw_input("Enter list of integers separated by a space:")
integers = [int(i) for i in x.split()]

for i in integers:
  driver.find_element_by_id('thetextbox').send_keys(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code sample from the selenium documentation:

You'll need probably need to wrap the loop around your get, find, and send_keys methods.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    x = raw_input("Enter list of integers separated by a space:")
    for i in input.split():
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        assert "Python" in driver.title
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys(i)
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
   driver.close()
```